# insert values not saved in a table in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following table: 
[image]

I want to insert values from the MySQL workbench. When I double click the table, I click tab: inserts. I insert the values, click File-> save, I close the window, then the next time, all the values does not exist. What is the problem ??

Comment: By `click save` you mean you clicked `apply changes to data`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `apply changes to data`.

[image]

Comment: I have a column idtable1, that I checked it as: PK, NN, AI. AI supposed to add a number starting from 1 and increment it in the next. In MSWB I'm getting this column empty. I specified its value as INT. Where is the problem ?

Comment: @JuryA How is your table defined? Did you set the column to `AUTO INCREMENT`? Defining the column as `int` is not enough.

Comment: @pythonscript: OP checked AI which is auto-increment.

Comment: @juergend Yikes, yes, I just saw that. I need to learn to read!